# Escaping JQuery AJAX Result And Retain It's Original Value

Tags: jquery, ajax, xss

If the return result value is `<script>alert('test');</script>`, is it possible to print exactly the value `<script>alert('test');</script>` inside my div tag?

```
$.ajax({
                    url:'${pageContext.request.contextPath}/node/get/2.do',
                    method:'GET',
                    data:{name:nodeName, parentId: parentId},
                    dataType:'json',
                    success:function (result, textStatus, xhr){
                        $('#div1').html(result);
                    }
                    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        $('#div1').html('error');                   } 
                }))
```

UPDATE:

Sorry it was a bad example to use a create url earlier. Changed it to GET instead. The main concern about using .html() directly is to deal with untrusted data being entered by user. What if var results returns the following value:

```
<center>
  <script>
    setInterval(function(){
      alert("you have xss!");
    }, 2000);
  </script>
</center>
```

While the expected value is

```
<center>Node 1</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$('#div1').html(result);
```

Try

```
$('#div1').text(result);
```

**NOTE :-**

Use `.text(…)` when you intend to display the value as a simple text(as in your case).

Use `.html(…)` when you intend to display the value as a html formatted text (or HTML content).

Read more on [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) and [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) here.

Comment: Hey thanks! What if my result returns both html and a value. Such as <center>hello</center> ?

Comment: if you want that your value should be interpreted as html then use `.html()` and when you want to print html tags as text only like in this scenario then use `.text()` as shown in my answer.@CodeBender

Comment: The concern is, how to deal with malicious code printing with .html()

Comment: @CodeBender..sorry i didn't get you..which malicious code you are talking here.????

Comment: sorry @Kartikeya for the late response. I have updated my question. Pardon me for the lack of clarity in the initial post.

Comment: @CodeBender...so you was asking for a way so that no one mess up with the html coming from server side..so now you already got the answer... great..but i answered as per your question before your update..so cheers..!!!..your problem is solved now..thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my question.

Previously when I escape the value returned in "result" variables, not only symbols are being escaped but spaces are escaped as well. After going through [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Why_Can.27t_I_Just_HTML_Entity_Encode_Untrusted_Data.3F) website again, I found the [ESAPI](https://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-java/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/org/owasp/esapi/codecs/HTMLEntityCodec.java)
library to do escaping on server side before returning to the AJAX Request.